# Passing Complex Objects to ASP.NET Web API Using FromUri

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

I want to bind the URL parameters to my `Point` object using attribute routing and the `[FromUri]` attribute such that the following URL is possible:

> /foo-1,2

```
public IHttpActionResult PostFoo(
    [FromBody] string content,
    [FromUri] Point point)
{
}

public class Point
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }

    // ...Other properties omitted for simplicity
}
```

I have tried the following Route attributes but none of these work:

```
[Route("foo-{a},{b}")]
[Route("foo-{A},{B}")]
[Route("foo-{point.A},{point.B}")]
```

Note that I can't use query string parameters because a badly built third party service does not accept ampersands in their URL's (Yes it's that bad). So I'm trying to build all query string parameters into the URL itself.

Comment: You may want to consider using the URL-Rewriter to rewrite the URL before it makes it to MVC.  Would make thing ridiculously easy for any url.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I was thinking of writing some kind of filter or model binder to do the same thing. I guess falling back to IIS is a valid option.

Comment: Model binder is much to late in the process to select a route.  You'd probably need to write a [RouteHandler](http://www.brainthud.com/cards/5218/24821/give-an-example-of-how-you-would-create-a-custom-route-handler-to-reroute-requests-with-a-certain-value-in-the-accept-http-he).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two Options I'm aware of is:

Use [URL Rewriter](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) to Globally take care of every and all routes. The advantage is that (I would hope) your publisher does have some type of standard url you can transform into a friendly MVC route.

If not then you'll probably have to write your own RouteHandler.  Not sure if you could use this globally, but you'd have to register it a lot (not that hard really).

```
public class CustomRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
{
  protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
  {
    var acceptValue = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Accept"];

    if( /* do something with the accept value */)
    {
        // Set the new route value in the
        // requestContext.RouteData.Values dictionary
        // e.g. requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = "Customer";
    }

    return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
  }
}
```

Then register it:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Custom",
  url: "{controller}/{action}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
).RouteHandler = new CustomRouteHandler();
```